# Safely Reuse Editor Templates Across Different Types

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc-editor-templates

Suppose I have the following partial view for `Decimal` located at `"~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Decimal.cshtml"`:

```
@model decimal?
@{
    var attrs = ViewData;

    if (ViewData["type"] == null)
    {
        attrs.Add("type", "number");
    }
}

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m, attrs)
```

I want to also use this template for properties of type `Int32`.  So I create the following at `"~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Int32.cshtml"`:

```
@model int?
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Decimal.cshtml", (decimal?)Model)
```

Is there a better way to reuse editor templates? Are there any consequences to this pattern that I may have missed?

(**Edit:** added explicit cast from `int` to `decimal?`.)

Answer (score 1):

You can define an EditorTemplate as a whole. Once defining for both data types.
For instance, you can use the following code samples:

Definition of EditorTemplate :

```
~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Number.cshtml
```

Uassage of Helper in View :

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.SomeValue)
```

definition in ViewModel Class is

```
[UIHint("Number")]
public int SomeValue { get; set; }
```

OR

```
[UIHint("Number")]
public decimal SomeValue { get; set; }
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without having to repeat "Number" for each property or for each call to `EditorFor`?

Comment: yes, it's not necessary and I updated my answer, try it.